# How do i res.send multiple parameters without the parameter names visible

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, mongodb, express

I made this code.

```
app.post("/addname", (req, res) => {
  var myData = new User(req.body);
  myData
    .save()
    .then(item => {
      res.send(req.body.firstName);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
    });
});
```

There is much more code to work with this, but what it basically does, it interacts with 2 inputs and a mongodb database, the data in question is a firstName and a lastName which makes a user, I click the button to send the data to the database and then I want this function to send me to another page which is called /addname to print out the newly added user.

Over all this works perfectly, the only problem is I can't figure out how to display more then a single parameter, as you can see res.send is only printing out the firstname of the user array I am taking from the database, writing a comma and then adding something like req.body.lastName is not working, I looked through the internet to see if I could find this problem and I did but not they way I wanted it, I mean using this method.

```
{
  firstName: req.body.firstName,
  lastName: req.body.lastName
}
```

Which results in this.

```
{"firstName":"Tommy","lastName":"Monsoo"}
```

Even though I just want it to look like this.

```
Tommy Monsoo
```

What am I doing wrong here, does the res.send function only work with arrays?!

Comment: Why do you think it only works with arrays? 1. That's an object, not an array. 2. The first thing you sent was a string, not an array. If just sends whatever you give it, and you're giving it an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to concatenate the two values like this :

`res.send( req.body.firstName + " " + req.body.lastName );`

Comment: Christ all mighty thank you! And I feel stupid all of a sudden, but thank you !

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the Answer if it truly fixed the issue you're having! :)